# Add custom tag in dynamically provisioned EBS using aws-ebs-csi-driver

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-eks

I am dynamically provisioning an EBS volume using the csi driver, I would like to add tags to help manage the volumes provisioned by K8S in the AWS console.

I managed to add tags to **all** provided disks by passing the tag in the driver installation [link](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/blob/master/charts/aws-ebs-csi-driver/values.yaml#L68), using this strategy it adds to all disks, however, I would like to add tags to differentiate disks.

Example of tags you would like to add: version name, namespace or environment

The following are manifests based on the AWS documentation.

manifest - StorageClass:

```
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: ebs-sc
  labels:
    Name: ebs-claim
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer
provisioner: ebs.csi.aws.com
parameters:
  type: "gp3"
  fsType: "ext4"
```

manifest - PVC:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: ebs-claim
  labels:
    Name: ebs-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  storageClassName: ebs-sc
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 4Gi
```

manifest - POD:

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: app
  labels:
    Name: ebs-claim
spec:
  containers:
    - name: app
      image: centos
      command: ["/bin/sh"]
      args: ["-c", "while true; do echo $(date -u) >> /data/out.txt; sleep 5; done"]
      volumeMounts:
        - name: persistent-storage
          mountPath: /data
  volumes:
    - name: persistent-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: ebs-claim
```

Comment: There's a [lively discussion in their issue tracker](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/issues/180) but as best I can tell, the answer is "you can't yet" using just their CSI driver. You'll need some glue code to watch those namespaces and apply the tags yourself, AIUI

Answer (score 2):

The AWS EBS CSI Driver supports tagging through `StorageClass.parameters` starting from v1.6.0.

If a key has the prefix `tagSpecification`, the CSI driver will treat the value as a key-value pair to be applied to the dynamically provisioned volume as tags. The CSI driver also supports runtime string interpolation on the tag values.

Example:

```yaml
kind: StorageClass
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: ebs-sc
provisioner: ebs.csi.aws.com
parameters:
  tagSpecification_1: "key1=value1"
  tagSpecification_2: "key2=hello world"
  tagSpecification_3: "key3="
  tagSpecification_4: 'backup={{ .PVCNamespace | contains "prod" }}'
  tagSpecification_5: 'billingID={{ .PVCNamespace | field "-" 2 | toUpper }}'
```

**NOTE**: Interpolated tags require the `--extra-create-metadata` flag to be enabled on the `external-provisioner` sidecar.

For details see [StorageClass Tagging](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/blob/master/docs/tagging.md#storageclass-tagging).

Answer (score 1):

See the `values.yaml` in the helm chart git repo:

- https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/blob/helm-chart-aws-ebs-csi-driver-2.8.0/charts/aws-ebs-csi-driver/values.yaml#L87
- https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/aws-ebs-csi-driver/blob/helm-chart-aws-ebs-csi-driver-2.8.0/charts/aws-ebs-csi-driver/values.yaml#L90

You should set `controller.k8sTagClusterId` and `controller.extraVolumeTags` variables to tag the AWS EBS resources.

As far as you configure it, the name of the EBS will look like `<EKS_NAME>-dynamic-pvc-<PVC_ID>` and all tags from `controller.extraVolumeTags` will be there too.

Your values for helm chart should should looks like this:

```yaml
controller:
  k8sTagClusterId: my-eks-cluster-name
  extraVolumeTags:
    tag1: value1
    tag2: value2
```